# Changing central meridian in QGIS causes problems?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, editing

I want to change the central meridian of my world map (WGS84) in QGIS from 0 to -80. The problem is that this distorts the map every time I try it.

[image: QGIS project showing country outline data. Countries at +/-180 degrees from the new central meridian are unclosed polygons.]

This is what I do:

- go to Settings/Custom CRS and then click on Add new CRS
- copy existing CRS (choosing WGS84 / World Mercator)
- Edit its parameters (changing only the central meridian) to: +proj=merc +lon_0=-80 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84   +units=m +no_defs
- go to Project Properties/CRS and choose my custom CRS

And then the whole map is distorted. It works fine when I do it in ArcGIS.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate, but leaving open for another day so Jakob can confirm