# World Mercator Projection with Chucotka region in right part?

Tags: coordinate-system, russia

How can I choose or modify World Mercator projection to display eastern part of Chucotka region in the right part of the map? I have already tried to change the parametr +lon_0, but the map looks like in the picture.

user projection parameters

```
+proj=merc +lon_0=+10 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You can see a similar issue in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/89618/81764. The basic solution is to cut all the features where they cross the dateline. That question has a link to a detailed solution in QGIS. If you need a solution in a different software, add that software tag to your question.

Comment: If you need a solution in a different software, don't just add that software tag to your question.  Also, describe in your question body precisely what you have tried using that software.